# Flask_Admin not including some columns in create / edit but are included in the list

Tags: flask, flask-admin

Basically what the title says: Flask-Admin is not including some columns in create / edit but are included in the list.

Flask-Admin is just not including 2 of the columns in the create or edit fields, but is including them in the list. Any idea why this might be happening? The two columns not included are flag_type and filters

```
filters = Column(JSONSchema(FeatureFlagsFiltersSchema),
                     doc="This field should contain filters for the feature flag applicability")

flag_type = Column(UnicodeTextEnum(FeatureFlagType), index=True,
                       doc="Specifies whether the feature flag is FE or BE related")
```

There are many other columns that are showing up fine such as name, ect.

I've tried doing something like below

```
form_create = ['code', 'label', 'doc', 'blanket_on_off_null', 'warn_after', 'ticket_id', 'usage_info', 'flag_type']
```

to force those columns to show up but they don't seem to be working. Thanks for the help! I can post more code if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably due to the complexity of these fields, flask-admin can't figure out what kind of form widget it is supposed to render for them. You can try adding them in `form_extra_fields` with proper field types e.g.:

```
from wtforms.fields import TextAreaField

class TestModelView(ModelView):
    form_extra_fields = {
        'filters': TextAreaField('filters')
    }
```